# Shell command to get directory with least access date/time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Is there any sort option available in find command to get directory with least access date/time

Comment: If you mean to do that without changing the access time in the process, you're likely out-of-luck (unless your filesystem supports read-only snapshots that can be mined for such metadata, as do AFS, ZFS and btrfs). mtime is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
 find . -type d -printf "%A@ %p\n" | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

If you prefer the filename without leading path, replace `%p` by `%f`.

Comment: I would add `-type d` since he is only looking for directories

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for me on cygwin/bash, because all dirs get current time as access time (`find` itself accesses the dirs).

Comment: @JeffY: My answer was intended to work with [Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/linux/info).

Comment: It'd be safer (ie. for filenames with newlines in their names) if this used NUL delimiters (thus also requiring `sort -z`). Reverse the sort to make the desired output first, and you can just send the output directly to `read`, thus removing the need for the `tail`.

Comment: ie. `{ read -r -d' ' time && IFS= read -r -d '' filename; } < <(find . -type d -printf '%A@ %p\0' | sort -z -r -n)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Thank you for this hint.

Answer (score 0):

- the below linux command displays the access and modified time along with size

  stat -f

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you please suggest how it can be used with sort in find command..

Answer (score 0):

A simple shell script will also do:

```
unset -v oldest
for i in "$dir"/*; do
    [ "$i" -ot "$oldest" -o "$oldest" = "" ] && oldest="$i"
done
```

**note:** to find the oldest directory use `"$dir"/*/` above (thanks Cyrus) and `-type d` below with the `find` command.

In bash if you need a recursive solution, then you can rewrite it as a while loop with *process substitution* using `find`

```
unset -v oldest
while IFS= read -r i; do
    [ "$i" -ot "$oldest" -o "$oldest" = "" ] && oldest="$i"
done < <(find "$dir" -type f)
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `"$i" -ot "$oldest"` by `"$oldest" -ot "$i"` and replace `"$dir"/*` by `"$dir"/*/` in your first version to find directory with least access date/time.

Comment: I like it. Thank you for the pointer. I'll update the answer. Wait -- why `"$oldest" -ot "$i"`? we are testing if `"$i" -ot "$oldest"`? We only want to update `oldest` if `i` is older -- right?

Comment: I understand the question so that the newest directory is searched.

Comment: The goal is atime, not mtime, right? Other than that, I'd also consider NUL-delimiting the output from `find`.

Comment: Mmmm.. I hadn't considered whether we were talking differences between `atime` or `mtime` - that would make a difference and need tweaking the `find` tests. Good point. OP will need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type d -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort | head -1
```

[source](https://superuser.com/a/552606/485024)

Comment: it will be a better answer if you describe your code there!

Answer (score 0):

This sound like more of a job for `ls`:

```
ls -ultd *|grep ^d
```

The problem with using `find`, at least on my system (cygwin/bash), is that `find` *accesses* the dirs, so all access-times result in current time, defeating your apparent purpose.

Comment: There is no filename parsing in the above. And if you've really got newlines *in* filenames, you're in a much worse world of hurt anyway.

Comment: One of the more interesting data loss incidents to happen at my former employers happened because someone writing a shell script assumed that all files in a directory would match `[a-z0-f]{24}`. When we had a buffer overflow dump random garbage -- which happened to include a whitespace-surrounded asterisk -- into a filename, fun ensued. And by "fun", I mean "unexpected deletion of multiple TB of records used to back customer billing". If you're assuming that something can never happen, you're writing code that can't deal with it happening.

Comment: ...and sure, there's no parsing in the example given here, but parsing has to happen before the output is programmatically usable, so the fact that that step isn't shown is a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -type d -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort
```

Comment: While this is probably a very good answer to the question please try to provide some background info. What does this command do?

Comment: He did ask for "access time", not modtime, so `%A` instead of `%T` there. But that runs into the problem identified in my answer -- `find` itself sets all access times to the current time (for dirs), defeating the purpose.

Comment: ...also, the use of newline delimiters is a poor selection, as newlines are allowed inside filenames.